# Problem with returning in recursion function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
word = ["cs", "is", "fun", "homework", "is", "sometimes", "fun",
"exams", "are", "not", "fun"].
 lst = ["fun", "is","not"]

def num(word,lst,sofar):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return sofar
    elif lst[0] in word == False:
        return num(word, lst[1:],sofar)
    else:
        sofar = sofar +1
        return num(word,lst,sofar)
```

function returns how many times the words in list lst occur in list word and returns it as sofar

The function should return 6 but it returns 0

Comment: I strongly suspect that your problem is a typo: `so_far` vs `sofar`.  You assign to `so_far`, but never use the value.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo while changing the names of the variable. The problem still persists.

Comment: The answer to this question should be 6 but it returns 0

Comment: Your code as amended still returns nothing.  The program initializes two lists, defines a function, and exits without calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have `word` and `lst` turned around in your logic. Your code shrinks the list that holds the things you look for - not the list where you look them up in.

Fix:

```
def num(word,lst,sofar):
    if not word:
        return sofar

    # ternary to add or not to add 1 to sofar
    return num(word[1:], lst, sofar+ (1 if word[0] in lst else 0)) 


word = ["cs", "is","fun", "homework","is", "sometimes", "fun", "exams", "are", "not", "fun"] 
lst = ["fun", "is","not"]

print(num(word,lst,0))
```

---

You could use a normal if as well:

```
def num(word,lst,sofar):
    if not word:
        return sofar

    if word[0] in lst:
        return num(word[1:], lst, sofar+1)
    else:
        return num(word[1:], lst, sofar)
```

Answer (score 0):

First: you declared `word` and `lst` wrong, it should be the other way around.
Second: you can do it without the if-else
Third: get rid of the sofar

```py
LST = [
    "cs", "is", "fun",
    "homework", "is", "sometimes", "fun",
    "exams", "are", "not", "fun"
]
WORD = ["fun", "is","not"]

def num(word, lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    inc = 1 if lst[0] in word else 0
    return num(word, lst[1:]) + inc

print(num(WORD, LST))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you were not moving onto the next word in the list when the word was found.

You were also iterating on the wrong list (swap `lst` and `word` around).

Try this:

```
def num(word, lst, sofar):
    if len(word) == 0:
        return sofar
    elif lst[0] in word == False:
        return num(word[1:], lst, sofar)
    else:
        sofar = sofar + 1
        return num(word[1:], lst, sofar)

print(num(word, lst, 0))
```

A slightly cleaner version:

```
def num(searchList, looking_for, sofar=0):
    if len(searchList) == 0:
        return sofar
    elif searchList[0] in looking_for:
        return num(searchList[1:], looking_for, sofar +1 )
    else:
        return num(searchList[1:], looking_for, sofar)


count = num(word, lst)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to recursion, my inclination is to keep it simple:

```
word = ["cs", "is", "fun", "homework", "is", "sometimes", "fun", "exams", "are", "not", "fun"]
lst = ["fun", "is", "not"]

def num(word, lst, sofar=0):
    if word:
        return num(word[1:], lst, sofar + (word[0] in lst))

    return sofar

print(num(word, lst))
```